Elemental fighting that isn't actually elemental
By elements, I don't mean stuff on the periodic table.
I also don't mean the "classic" either. (Fire, water, air, earth)
In my world, the elements are fire, water, plant, and lightning (There's a lot more, as any user can create their own fighting style, but that's irrelevant to the question). When I draw the art in the book, I do draw the elements in the techniques being used (it's an action book, the elemental fighting is essentially the equivalent of a martial art in this world) however, in-world, the elements aren't actually there. They're just visual effects in the book to make it more interesting, but don't actually exist in the world of the book. How could I realistically explain that it doesn't exist, but at the same time acknowledge it's there?
(If this doesn't fit here, please migrate to writing.)

Is this like a manga with several panels per page? Or is it like a one-pager showing a character having a certain stance? Is it telling a story where those effects come into play or is it just an art book? Can you maybe give one example page?

@Antares It's a manga-style book. I don't have it on me right now, but I'll add an example of one of the existing fight scenes as soon as I can.

Very likely this will be migrated as it is definitely more about writing techniques than the setup of your world, but I still answered as I would on writing as the two do share a considerable overlap.

Hi, Deko. I'm sorry, but I'm going to have to vote to close this question. You're asking about stylistic choices in illustrating your elements. Worldbuilding is focused on the plausible cause-and-effect that goes into the background world in which stories are told.

This doesn't seem to be worldbuilding. It sounds to me like (not a writing problem but) an art-trope problem. Read some superhero comics -  eg. Magneto's power is illustrated even though invisible. It's an accepted convention.

Aw come on, that is kind of narrow minded to close vote this. If the author is drawing his world or writing about it should not matter. It is aimed at how to create a plausible world that is using a kind of magic. Granted, it is kind of a corner case. Still, I liked the question.

If I understand correctly, the fighting styles are element based, but don't contain actual elements? This reminds me of the old Chinese fighting styles being named after animals. Flying tigers, hidden dragons, kicking cranes, etc. the animals aren't actually present in the attack, but if I were to draw that you can be sure I'd include the force in the shape of an animal for visual effect.
You can establish this by having a character who is unable to understand or recognise certain techniques. Instead of seeing the element like the reader, they just see some fancy moves and don't know what they mean. This establishes the fact that in world the characters don't see what the reader sees, in the most unobtrusive way. Someone else can then explain how to recognise the techniques and how they work in your world to the reader, disguised as explaining it to this character.

Those attacks/stances were/are modeled very close to the real animal stances and you would immediately recognize them outside a fighting situation where you have enough time admiring it. But I understand and like were the second part of your answer goes very much! Nice idea!

Decorative Borders.
Consider decorative, braided borders around the page or panel that illustrate the "element".
You know, like ornaments either in the corners or running around the whole page.

I'm accepting the other answer because its more detailed but I intend to incorporate both ideas. Thanks!
